# Alternative proof of the converse of the mean value theorem.

Tags: limits, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

I have proven the converse of the MVT before, but I have not seen it done like this and I do not understand it.

Consider the limit:

$ \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{2n}{r^2}[\frac{1}{n \alpha (n)} \int_{\delta B(0,1)} u(x+r\omega)dS(\omega)-u(x)]$

In the above, $\alpha(n)$ represents the volume of the unit ball.

It says that you can use a Taylor expansion with remainder, and note that

$\int_{\delta B(0,1)}x_i=\int_{\delta B(0,1)}x_jx_k $ for $j\neq k$,

then it can be shown that this limit is equal to $ \Delta u(x)$, and then we conclude that the limit is $0$. I cannot begin to see how to reduce this limit to the laplacian of $u$. I am not very familiar with PDEs, but I am trying to learn. Can someone demonstrate how to manipulate this limit?

Comment: What is the converse of the mean value theorem?

Comment: The wording may not be exact on my part. If we have a harmonic function, we have the MVT. This is trying to show that if the MVT holds, then we can simplify this limit to show that the function is harmonic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Proposition: Suppose that $x_0\in \mathbb R^n$ and $u \in C^2(B_{2r}(x_0))$ for some $r>0$. Then $$\lim_{\rho \to 0^+} \frac1{\rho^2}\bigg \{  \frac1{\mathcal H^{n-1}(\partial B_\rho(x_0))}\int_{\partial B_\rho(x_0)} u(x) \, d\mathcal H^{n-1}_x -u(x_0) \bigg\}=\frac1{2n} \Delta u(x_0). $$
>
> Proof . By Taylor's Theorem, $$u(x) = u(x_0) +Du(x_0) \cdot x + \frac12 x \cdot (D^2u(x_0)x) + o(\vert x \vert^2) \tag{$\ast$}$$ as $\vert x\vert \to 0$. Since $ x \mapsto D_iu(x_0) x_i$ is odd across the $x_i$-plane it follows that $$ \int_{\partial B_\rho(x_0)} D_iu(x_0) x_i \, d\mathcal H^{n-1}_x =0$$ for all $i=1,\dots n$. Similarly, $x \mapsto D_{ij}u(x_0)x_ix_j$ for $i\neq j$ is odd across the $x_i$-plane so $$\int_{\partial B_\rho(x_0)} D_{ij}u(x_0) x_ix_j \, d\mathcal H^{n-1}_x =0 $$ for all $i,j=1,\dots, n$, $i\neq j$. Integrating $(\ast)$ over $\partial B_r(x_0)$ gives \begin{align*}\frac1{\mathcal H^{n-1}(\partial B_\rho(x_0))}\int_{\partial B_\rho(x_0)} u(x) \, d\mathcal H^{n-1}_x &=u(x_0)+\frac12 \frac1{\mathcal H^{n-1}(\partial B_\rho(x_0))}\sum_{i=1}^n\int_{\partial B_\rho(x_0)} D_{ii}u(x_0)x_i^2 \, d\mathcal H^{n-1}_x +o (\rho^2). \\
> &=u(x_0)+\frac12 \frac1{\mathcal H^{n-1}(\partial B_\rho(x_0))}\sum_{i=1}^nD_{ii}u(x_0)\int_{\partial B_\rho(x_0)} x_i^2 \, d\mathcal H^{n-1}_x +o (\rho^2).  \end{align*} Then, by symmetry, $$\int_{\partial B_\rho(x_0)} x_i^2 \, d\mathcal H^{n-1}_x = \frac1n\int_{\partial B_\rho(x_0)} \vert x \vert^2 \, d\mathcal H^{n-1}_x=\frac{\rho^2\mathcal H^{n-1}(\partial B_\rho(x_0))}{n}. $$ Thus, \begin{align*}
> \frac1{\mathcal H^{n-1}(\partial B_\rho(x_0))}\int_{\partial B_\rho(x_0)} u(x) \, d\mathcal H^{n-1}_x &=u(x_0)+\frac{\rho^2}{2n}\sum_{i=1}^nD_{ii}u(x_0) +o (\rho^2)\\
> & =u(x_0)+\frac{\rho^2}{2n}\Delta u(x_0) +o (\rho^2)
> \end{align*} which gives the result. $\square$

The converse to the mean value properties say if $$ u(x_0)= \frac1{\mathcal H^{n-1}(\partial B_\rho(x_0))}\int_{\partial B_\rho(x_0)} u(x) \, d\mathcal H^{n-1}_x $$ for all $B_r(x_0) \subset \subset \Omega$ then $\Delta u=0$ in $\Omega$. This directly follows from the Proposition since $$\frac1{\mathcal H^{n-1}(\partial B_\rho(x_0))}\int_{\partial B_\rho(x_0)} u(x) \, d\mathcal H^{n-1}_x  -u(x_0)=0 $$for all $B_r(x_0) \subset \subset \Omega$.